# How do i fade in a semi transparent UIVIew and dismiss when bg is touched?

Tags: ios, uiview, transparent

I have no clue how to deal with animations, I'm looking to fade in a semitransparent view and have it dismiss when the background is tapped like how the Tumblr app has for their compose screen.

This is what I have so far. It adds in a semitransparent view but doesn't have the fade in effect like Tumblr.

```
UIView *modalView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[modalView setOpaque: NO];
[modalView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithAlphaComponent: 0.9];
[[self view] addSubview: modalView];
```

Comment: Are you trying to display a model view? Do you use multiple view controllers to accomplish the job?

Comment: @RandyMarsh yes im trying to display a modal view but with transparency so i can still see view controller similar to the tumblr app

Comment: Why are you adding `modalView` to the the view controller's view? If `modalView` is your modal view, use a view controller which manages `modalView` and use `presentViewController:animated:completion:`. On the modal view controller, set the transition style to `UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve` using `-setTransitionStyle:` beforehand.

Comment: @RandyMarsh sorry im using a uiview but i named it modal view ,bad taste...

Comment: @RandyMarsh what about transparency to see the my viewcontroller

Comment: But what does the view do then? If that view fades in and takes over the screen (like a compose view), it's a modal view. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve but it looks like you need a combination of `UIView` animation and `UITapGestureRecognizer`

Use this code to fade in a view (adjust start and end alpha values appropriately):

```
[modalView setAlpha:0];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^(void) {
                    [myView setAlpha:1.0;
                 }
                 completion:NULL];
```

And this to create a gesture recognizer:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapgr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didTapView)];
tapgr.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
[timeView addGestureRecognizer:tapgr];
```

`didTapView` is your method to dismiss the view.

Hope this helps.

Comment: aww man thanks this works perfect for me it fades in and dismisses when tapped, how can i reverse the animation for fading out?

Comment: Use the same code but set the alpha in the animation block to 0.

Comment: thanks worked perfect... now tht i added the view to the superview when it fades out is it removed from superview? or do i need to call this in my didTapview gesture?

Comment: you need to manually remove it from the superview - best place to do that is in the completion block of the animation

Comment: I couldnt thankyou enough man really appreciate the hand, my first time workin with animations.. now to imitate tumblrs icon animation -_- lol.. my app is coming soon app.flaksburyst.com thanks Andy!

Comment: no problem, glad to help - as you see basic animations are very easy in iOS!

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to add an tap recognizer into this semi transparent view? See [UITapGestureRecognizer class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: not yet i havent gotten past the first part of animating in the semi transparent view over my current view

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, your problem is that there's no animation. Animation is simple:

```
UIView *modalView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[modalView setOpaque: NO];
[modalView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithAlphaComponent: 0.9];
[[self view] addSubview: modalView];

[modalView setAlpha: 0];
[UIView animateWithDuration: 0.5 animations: ^{
    [modalView setAlpha: 1];
}
```

Explore `UIView`'s other animation methods for completion handlers, etc.

Comment: thank you this works perfect im tryin to figure how to fade out now for dismissing the view